# knitr::kable is there a way to reduce the font size?

Tags: r, knitr, r-markdown

I am using this code chunk

````
```{r, echo = FALSE}
  knitr::kable(df)
```
````

However I would like to reduce the size of all font inside this table so that the output looks nicer. Is there a way to do that with kable or is there another package which supports it?

Answer (score 58, accepted):

You can also try `library(kableExtra)`. It has a lot of options to customise the table.

Specifically, for font size: https://haozhu233.github.io/kableExtra/awesome_table_in_html.html#font_size

```
df %>%
  kable("html") %>%
  kable_styling(font_size = 7)
```

Comment: kableExtra works great for HTML and LaTeX tables, but isn't compatitble with other formats

Answer (score 13):

I use **\tiny** before the function and **\normalsize** after it, which works for .pdf using the formats *latex* and *markdown*.

@r0berts' request:

Here is a full example:

````
---
title: "Test"
output:
  pdf_document: default
date: "2023-11-30"
---

```{r setup, include=FALSE}
knitr::opts_chunk$set(echo = TRUE)
```

```{r}
library(knitr)
kable(iris[1:5,])
```


\tiny 

```{r}
kable(iris[1:5,])
```

\normalsize
````

This renders this as .pdf

[image]

Comment: Sorry, how do you use this, could you please give an example? Thanks

Comment: I've updated the post with an example :)

Comment: Great, that's perfect, thanks. Would you happen to know if there is a way to apply size (tiny or other) to just one column?

Comment: Mhmm, not really. Do HTML tags work within the table? If so that would be something I'd try.

Comment: Thanks, I am more orientated towards latex based solutions as my target output is PDF. But I will further investigate `column_spec` in `kableextra`.

Answer (score 5):

When you are happy with a global setting, use css on `.table`. To set it for one table, the only method I am aware of uses a `div`. Both methods cannot be used for latex etc, but the global method looks cleaner to me, because formating is delegated to a separate css.

````
---
title: "Small kable"
output: 
  html_document:
    css: kable.css

---

# Global setting

```{r}
library(knitr)
kable(iris[1:5,])
```


# Local setting, not portable
<div class="verysmall">

```{r}
kable(iris[1:5,])
```

</div>
````

CSS File

```
.table{
  width:auto;
  font-size: 12px;
}

.verysmall .table{
  font-size: 8px;
}
```

I also use auto-formatting for kable-tables in most cases.

Comment: It cannot be used when output is Latex or Doc.

Answer (score 1):

Dieter's answer worked for me. My first time using CSS in rmarkdown. Instead of using a separate CSS file, I embedded the following code towards the top of my rmarkdown doc, as referenced here: https://bookdown.org/yihui/rmarkdown-cookbook/html-css.html.

````
    ```{css, echo = FALSE}
    .verysmall .table{
      font-size: 8px;
    }
    ```
````