# R markdown ioslides - change kable font size with CSS

Tags: css, r, markdown, kable, ioslides

I'm trying to fit a large table on one slide. I'm using kable.
I tried `{.smaller}` but it's not quite enough so I thought I'd use a .css but it isn't working either.

I created a sample presentation to illustrate the problem. I tried knitting it and it shows up the same way as in my other presentation (which is quite long which is why I excluded it here)

My code:

```
---
title: "test"
author: "Test Author"
date: "5 Februar 2018"
output: 
  ioslides_presentation:
    test: presentation.css
---

{r setup, include=FALSE}
knitr::opts_chunk$set(echo = FALSE)
library(knitr)


## Test slide

{r}
table <- data.frame(
  index=1:10,
  long_text=c("long text here: asdfghhjoqweqwrqwrqwrasfasdfghhjoqweqwrqwrqwrasfasdfghhjoqweqwrqwrqwrasfasdfghhjoqweqwrqwrqwrasf",
    "long text here: asdfghhjoqweqwrqwrqwrasf",
    "long text here: asdfghhjoqweqwrqwrqwrasf",
    "long text here: asdfghhjoqweqwrqwrqwrasf",
    "long text here: asdfghhjoqweqwrqwrqwrasf",
    "long text here: asdfghhjoqweqwrqwrqwrasf",
    "long text here: asdfghhjoqweqwrqwrqwrasf",
    "long text here: asdfghhjoqweqwrqwrqwrasf",
    "long text here: asdfghhjoqweqwrqwrqwrasf",
    "long text here: asdfghhjoqweqwrqwrqwrasf")
)
kable(table)


## Test slide css {.test}

{r}
table <- data.frame(
  index=1:10,
  long_text=c("long text here: asdfghhjoqweqwrqwrqwrasfasdfghhjoqweqwrqwrqwrasfasdfghhjoqweqwrqwrqwrasfasdfghhjoqweqwrqwrqwrasf",
    "long text here: asdfghhjoqweqwrqwrqwrasf",
    "long text here: asdfghhjoqweqwrqwrqwrasf",
    "long text here: asdfghhjoqweqwrqwrqwrasf",
    "long text here: asdfghhjoqweqwrqwrqwrasf",
    "long text here: asdfghhjoqweqwrqwrqwrasf",
    "long text here: asdfghhjoqweqwrqwrqwrasf",
    "long text here: asdfghhjoqweqwrqwrqwrasf",
    "long text here: asdfghhjoqweqwrqwrqwrasf",
    "long text here: asdfghhjoqweqwrqwrqwrasf")
)
kable(table)
```

And my .css:

```
.test{
   font-size: 50%;
}
```

Comment: check this post and put bigger size instead of small https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40840986/knitrkable-is-there-a-way-to-reduce-the-font-size

Comment: I tried that and I also tried kableExtra. It works for html output but not for ioslides :(

Comment: I think I found an answer: adding `td {font-size: 16px !important;}` in the CSS style ...
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9245353/what-does-important-mean-in-css

Comment: @BenBolker isn't the main/first issue here that the `yaml` header says `test: presentation.css` instead of `css: presentation.css`?

Comment: I didn't test this example - I had a similar issue (not even with kable, just with a regular multiline table in markdown -> ioslides), so I didn't try testing it.  There's definitely an issue that the `td` characteristics *either* have to be specified as in @technophobe01's answer, or with `!important`; simplify specifying a `td` style doesn't override the rmdtable-specific characteristics ...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can do this by modifying the css `table` and `td` attributes.

### Result:

[image]

Example CSS and Code:

#### presentation.css

```
table.rmdtable td, table th {
    font-size: 40%;
    padding: 1em 0.5em;
    line-height: 18px;
}
```

#### rmarkdownfile

````
---
title: "test"
author: "Test Author"
date: "5 Februar 2018"
output: 
  ioslides_presentation:
    css: presentation.css
---

```{r setup, include=FALSE}
knitr::opts_chunk$set(echo = FALSE)
library(knitr)
```

## Test slide

```{r}
table <- data.frame(
  index=1:10,
  long_text=c("long text here: asdfghhjoqweqwrqwrqwrasfasdfghhjoqweqwrqwrqwrasfasdfghhjoqweqwrqwrqwrasfasdfghhjoqweqwrqwrqwrasf",
    "long text here: asdfghhjoqweqwrqwrqwrasf",
    "long text here: asdfghhjoqweqwrqwrqwrasf",
    "long text here: asdfghhjoqweqwrqwrqwrasf",
    "long text here: asdfghhjoqweqwrqwrqwrasf",
    "long text here: asdfghhjoqweqwrqwrqwrasf",
    "long text here: asdfghhjoqweqwrqwrqwrasf",
    "long text here: asdfghhjoqweqwrqwrqwrasf",
    "long text here: asdfghhjoqweqwrqwrqwrasf",
    "long text here: asdfghhjoqweqwrqwrqwrasf")
)
kable(table)
```

## Test slide css {.test}

```{r}
table <- data.frame(
  index=1:10,
  long_text=c("long text here: asdfghhjoqweqwrqwrqwrasfasdfghhjoqweqwrqwrqwrasfasdfghhjoqweqwrqwrqwrasfasdfghhjoqweqwrqwrqwrasf",
    "long text here: asdfghhjoqweqwrqwrqwrasf",
    "long text here: asdfghhjoqweqwrqwrqwrasf",
    "long text here: asdfghhjoqweqwrqwrqwrasf",
    "long text here: asdfghhjoqweqwrqwrqwrasf",
    "long text here: asdfghhjoqweqwrqwrqwrasf",
    "long text here: asdfghhjoqweqwrqwrqwrasf",
    "long text here: asdfghhjoqweqwrqwrqwrasf",
    "long text here: asdfghhjoqweqwrqwrqwrasf",
    "long text here: asdfghhjoqweqwrqwrqwrasf")
)

kable(table)
```
````

### Explanation

My recommendation is you open the presentation in your browser, for example, chrome. Launch the development tools and play with the `css` attributes. You can then build this into your presentation .css file.

[image]

#### Recommended Reading:

Rather than modifying the overall slide deck formatting. I'd recommend you read up on applying `css` formatting to specific slides. For example only your two test slides.

https://bookdown.org/yihui/rmarkdown/custom-css-1.html#slide-ids-and-classes

I hope this points you in the right direction.

Comment: I'm sorry I had forgotten to accept the answer. It's 3 years later but thank you again.

Comment: No worries, always happy and willing to help. Stay safe and well.